# Undefined variable: request

Tags: laravel

When I tried to upload the file it shows error:

> Undefined variable: request

This is where I used it:
UploadController:

```
if($request->hasFile('file')){
        $file = $request ->file('file');
        $fileName = $file->getClientOriginalName();
        $destinationPath = config('app.fileDesinationPath').'/'.$fileName;
        $uploads = Storage::put($destinationPath,file_get_contents($file->getRealPath()));

    }
    return redirect()->to('/upload');
```

**What's wrong here?**

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Add `Request $request` parameter in your function. Example:

```
public function yourFunction(Request $request)
{
    if($request->hasFile('file')){
        $file = $request ->file('file');
        $fileName = $file->getClientOriginalName();
        $destinationPath = config('app.fileDesinationPath').'/'.$fileName;
        $uploads = Storage::put($destinationPath,file_get_contents($file->getRealPath()));

    }
    return redirect()->to('/upload');
}
```

Please read the documentation thoroughly: http://laravel.com/docs

You can also watch Laravel tutorials here: http://laracasts.com

Comment: thank you I did that, But, now, It shows: Class 'App\Http\Controllers\Storage' not found.

Comment: I think using request() helper function, as stated @Amit Gupta,  is the more appropriate way esp. if one is accessing request outside a controller

Comment: Works fine. Thank you.

Answer (score 7):

You can also use [`request()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/helpers#method-request) helper function as:

```
if(request()->hasFile('file')) {
    ...
}
```

> The request function returns the current request instance.

Comment: This is the correct answer esp. if one wants to access request from blade

Comment: I agree, this is the best answer. No need to pass an extra argument to your function.

Answer (score 2):

Use `Request::hasFile` instead of `$request`. Example:

```
if(Request::hasFile('file')){
    $file = Request::file('file');
    $fileName = $file->getClientOriginalName();
    $destinationPath = config('app.fileDesinationPath').'/'.$fileName;
    $uploads = Storage::put($destinationPath,file_get_contents($file->getRealPath()));

}
return redirect()->to('/upload'); `
```

Answer (score 1):

To access the $request variable you'll need to add it to your methods paramters

```
public function myFunction(Request $request)
{ 
   // access $request here
}
```

In order to make this work you'll need to add

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
```

If you like to validate and authorize in your request you can create your own request instead of using Illuminates Request Class directly just use

```
php artisan make:request MyRequest
```

You'll find and authorize method and a part to return validation rules.

Comment: thank you I did that, But, now, It shows: Class 'App\Http\Controllers\Storage' not found

Answer (score 0):

Apparently there isn't a `$request` injected in your method (I think, you have only posted part of your method). Check this and add it as parameter if necessary.